# Finding expected value of a random variable that depends on another random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Hello I am working on an assignment and I am a little stuck on how to progress on a particular question.

So here's the question specifics:

A coffee shop prides itself on only selling beans that have been freshly roasted the same morning.  The amount of beans that the coffee shop roasts each morning,R(’00 kg), is a random variable described by the probability density function

$f(r) = -6(r-1)^2+1.5, 0.5 < r < 1.5$

Given that the roasted amount on an arbitrary day is $R=r$, the amount sold in any particular day,S(’00 kg), is uniformly distributed such that $S < r$. Find $E[S]$.

What I have is that

$\begin{align}E[S] &= E[E[S|R]]\\
 &=E[-6(R^2-2R+1)+1.5]\\
 &=E[-6R^2+12R-6] + 1.5\\
 &=-6E[R^2]+12E[R] -4.5\\
 &=-6\int_{0.5}^{1.5}r^2(-6r^2+12r-6)dr+12\int_{0.5}^{1.5}r(-6r^2+12r-6)dr)dr -4.5\\
&=3.45 - 6-4.5\\
&=-7.05\end{align}$

but this result doesn't make any sense to the question so clearly I am doing something wrong.
If someone could give me a nudge in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Try using integration directly:  $\int_{1/2}^{3/2} \int_0^r s(-6(r-1)^2+3/2)/r ds dr$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sales $S$ conditional on $R=r$ has a uniform distribution from 0 to $r$.  Therefore, the conditional mean of $S|R=r$ is $r/2$.  So

$$E(S)=E_R(E(S|R))=E_R(R/2)=\int_{1/2}^{3/2} (r/2)(-6(r-1)^2+3/2)dr=1/2$$

Comment: can you please help me to understand why the integral is from $\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{3}{4}$ I don't understand why it isn't just from $\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{3}{2}$?

Comment: That's because I was sloppy.  Sorry about that.  It should be as you say $1/2$ to $3/2$.  I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

S is distributed uniformly $[0 ,r]$. So,  $f(s)=\frac{1}{r}$.

$E[s]=E_{R}[E[S|R]]=\int_{0.5}^{1.5}(0.5(r))f(r)dr$

Comment: If I did it correctly, your integral results in 3/4 when the answer is 1/2.

Comment: Thanks for fixing $f(s)$.